# If a 32-bit microprocessor has 24-bits of address space, why is the answer for the maximum number of addresses (2^24) given in bytes and not bits?

Tags: memory, cpu, bus

I'm working on this for homework and it seems all of my classmates and various online sources are saying that the simple calculation of 2^24-bits results in ~16,000,000-bytes instead of bits. Why is this? My understanding of it is that the answer would be ~16,000,000-bits, which would be converted to ~2,000,000-bytes because 1 byte is 8 bits.

Comment: Each address refers to a whole byte, not a bit. Memory isn't *bit*-addressable, it's *byte*-addressable.

Comment: @DragonLord, only if you're talking about modern systems.  Ancient computers (think: PDP-10 era) were typically word-addressible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DragonLord says, it's because you cannot *address* individual bits; each address points at the start of a byte, and all operations work with *at least* one byte units.

Similarly, if the machine was word-addressed (as some have been in the past), its memory size would also be expressed similarly:

> The PDP-8's basic configuration had a main memory of 4,096 twelve-bit words

Comment: Ah, so it's like working with statistical sets where the bits inside the addressable bytes are the elements within the sets and the maximum addressable space contains the family of sets?

Answer (score 0):

Another reason to address bytes rather than bits is because it also gives an immediate boost to the amount of data that can be stored and accessed. It also improves overall memory bandwidth as data is always pulled from memory in a multiple of byte blocks instead of bit-by-bit. Accessing memory a single bit at a time is inefficient if you know that the minimum useful block you are going to need to do anything useful is a single byte.

Even back when computers had small amounts of memory and low address line counts the ability to pull a byte at a time would have been a performance boost, and having access to 16 megabytes would have meant much larger programs could be made than if you only had access to 16 megabits (2 megabytes) of memory.